# Decode error translating extended ASCII hex string

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.9, I am taking an input string and part of it contains a field which may be a hex string, e.g. 0x79 in the below string.

> |Microsoft Cabinet (CAB)|0x79|TimeReceived=2022-09-02

I want to convert it to a string so that it can be used further in my code. However the code below is only working for 0 to 127.

This becomes b'^' and works fine

```
d1 = "5E"       # ^
bytes_array = bytes.fromhex(d1)
value = bytes_array.decode()
```

This becomes b'\xa6' and decode() raised an exception:

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 0: invalid start byte'

```
d2 = "A6"       # ¦
bytes_array = bytes.fromhex(d2)
value = bytes_array.decode()
```

Ultimately all I want is for the hex string to be converted to the equivalent character, e.g. ^ or ¦ in this case.

Comment: I think I fixed it by doing this: bytes_array.decode('iso-8859-1'), but I don't know how portable it is or why it really works?

Comment: Because `decode`s default encoding is UTF-8, and the UTF-8 encoding of U+00A6 requires two bytes.

Comment: right, I get you, I thought utf8 was variable byte lenth and 1 was ok as it mapped to ASCII? or am i totally wrong?

Comment: Not totally wrong. But "extended ASCII" is not ASCII. Codes greater than or equal to 0x80 need more than one byte.

Comment: In fact, there is really no such thing as "extended ASCII". At least, it doesn't say anything about the nature of the extension. ISO-8859-X (for a variety of values of X) are all different extensions. But ASCII only uses codes 0-127.

Answer (score 0):

I replicate your situation in my system and it works perfectly.

You can try this:

```
d2 = "A6"       # |
bytes_array = bytes.fromhex(d2)
value = bytes_array.decode('windows-1252')
print(value)
```

Comment: Thanks. See my comment in my original, i got it to work using iso-8859-1. Which is the more preferred character set for this type of work, on the presumption that it could be running from any server?

Comment: @Neil: The preferred character set is the one which was used to produce the hex code in the first place. That's dependent on the client, not the server, and figuring it out might be a challenge. If you get it wrong, then you'll get the wrong character, which may or may not be disastrous.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to produce a character with a specific Unicode codepoint, you can just use `char(int(d2, 16))`, which is a lot easier than roundtripping through `bytes` and trying to figure out an appropriate character set.

However, it might not correctly capture the intention of whoever produced the file in the first place. To get that right, you have to know which encoding was used to generate the hex value; different "extended ASCII" codings have different mappings for some or all of the codepoints. If you need to use an encoding which is not the same as the one used for the Unicode codepoints 128-255, then your approach is valid, but, again, you need to know which encoding to specify as the argument to the `decode` member function. The default encoding is `utf-8`, which certainly will not work since `¦` (and other codepoints in the range 128-2047) occupy two bytes in UTF-8.